# I cant put a kendo dropdownlist readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a kendoDropDownList and I can´t put it readonly, i tried all this:

```
$("#PreguntaPA008").kendoComboBox();
var combobox = $("#PreguntaPA008").data("kendoComboBox");
combobox.readonly(true);

var dataSource = $("#PreguntaPA008").data("kendoDropDownList");
dataSource.readonly();
var dataSource = $("#PreguntaPA008").data("kendoDropDownList").attr('readonly', true);

$("#PreguntaPA008").readonly(true);

$("#PreguntaPA008").attr("disabled", "disabled");

var siglaPregunta = "PA008";
const query = aplicarAComplemento ? `#Pregunta${siglaPregunta} > [name^="ComPre_"]:input` : `#${siglaPregunta}`;
$(query).attr('readonly', true);

$("#PreguntaPA008").kendoDropDownList({
    readonly: true
});

var dropdownlist = $("#PreguntaPA008").data("kendoDropDownList");
dropdownlist.enable(false);

$("#PreguntaPA008").kendoComboBox({
    enable: false
});

$("#PreguntaPA008").kendoComboBox({
    readonly: true
});

// Lo saca dos veces
$("#Pre_1658").kendoComboBox({
    readonly: true
});

// No hace nada
$("#Name_1658").kendoComboBox({
    readonly: true
});
```

When in the browser i inspect the element, i get

[image]

Why i cant get the element in readonly true?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this quick example with work for you:
https://dojo.telerik.com/InaMowep

It is a simple dropdown list and the button's either turn the dropdown list on or off i.e. `readonly vs editable` when calling the readonly method and wanting to set it to readonly you don't have to pass a true value to it. simply calling the function sets it to readonly as per the api details: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/methods/readonly

Answer (score 0):

The first one:

```
$("#PreguntaPA008").kendoComboBox();
var combobox = $("#PreguntaPA008").data("kendoComboBox");
combobox.readonly(true);
```

Should work. It should prevent the user from modifying it, BUT it still looks as editable. Check documentation [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox/methods/readonly)

In the other hand, if you do:

```
$("#PreguntaPA008").kendoComboBox();
var combobox = $("#PreguntaPA008").data("kendoComboBox");
combobox.enable(false);
```

It gets disabled (grayout) and you cannot even select it. Documentation [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox/methods/enable)

The following example creates two switches for dynamically change `enable` and `readonly`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // create ComboBox from input HTML element
  var cb = $("#PreguntaPA008").kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: [{
        text: "Cotton",
        value: "1"
      },
      {
        text: "Polyester",
        value: "2"
      },
      {
        text: "Cotton/Polyester",
        value: "3"
      },
      {
        text: "Rib Knit",
        value: "4"
      }
    ],
    filter: "contains",
    suggest: true,
    index: 3,
    enable: true,
    readonly: false
  }).data("kendoComboBox");

  $("#enable").kendoSwitch({
    change: function(e) {
      cb.enable(e.checked);
    }
  });

  $("#readonly").kendoSwitch({
    change: function(e) {
      cb.readonly(e.checked);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.119/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.119/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


<div id="example" role="application">
  Enable: <input type="checkbox" id="enable" checked="checked" /><br/> Read-only: <input type="checkbox" id="readonly" /><br/>
  <input id="PreguntaPA008" placeholder="Select fabric..." style="width: 100%;" />
</div>
```